# Recursive function structure in VBA

Tags: vba, recursion, dynamic

I'm trying to write a recursive function so that it calculates the sum of the products of the combinations of values in a dynamic array. Right now I've been trying to make it work for a simpler case, but I really don't quite understand the structure I should follow for a recursive function. In this case there's supposed to be the sum of 28 two factor products, resulting 1.4

```
Sub SuPC()
 Dim k As Long
 Dim s As Long
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long

 k = 8
 s = 2

 HSum i, j, s, k
End Sub

Function HSum(i As Long, j As Long, s, k) As Double
 Dim P As Variant
 Dim z() As Double
 Dim Tot As Double
 ReDim z(0 To (k * s) - 1)

 P = Array(1 / 2, 1 / 3, 1 / 4, 1 / 5, 1 / 6, 1 / 7, 1 / 8, 1 / 9)


 If i <= k Then
     HSum i + 1, j, s, k
     If j <= s Then
         HSum i, j + 1, s, k
         If z(i) = 0 Then z(i) = 1
         z(i) = P(j) * z(i)
     End If
     Tot = z(i) + Tot
 End If
 Range("J11") = Tot
End Function
```

If *s* and *k* were low fixated values, I could use For loops but the point is for them to be variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use tail recursion as this is just a sum of the products,
see here an example for tail recursion factoring.

```
Public Function fact_tail(n As Double) As Double
'Tail Recursion

'fact 4     = 4 * fact 3
'           = 4* 3 * fact 2
'           = 4* 3 * 2 * fact 1
'           = 4* 3 * 2 * 1

'fact 4     = go(4, 1)
'           = go((n - 1), (a * n))
'           = go((4-1),(1*4))
'           = go(3, 4)
'           = go(3-1, 3*4)
'           = go(2, 12)
'           = go(2-1, 12*2)
'           = go(1, 24)
'           = 4* 3 * 2 * 1 = 24
            
fact_tail = go_fact(n, 1)

End Function
Private Function go_fact(n, a)
    
    If n <= 1 Then
        go_fact = a
    Else
        go_fact = go_fact((n - 1), (a * n))
    End If
    
End Function
```